# App crashes with Fatal signal - /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so And /system/lib64/libhwui.so

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am working on an App having multiple Fingerprint scanner SDK integrated, After changing targedtSdk to 29 App started getting crash with Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV). Below is the stack trace that I got from logs. Crash backtrace pointing to /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so and /system/lib64/libhwui.so

**Beginning of Crash 1:-**

Check failed: found_virtual Didn't find oat method index for virtual method: void android.Manifest$permission.()

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4 in tid 15945

E/crash_dump64(16647): unknown process state: t
I/crash_dump64(16647): obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
I/crash_dump64(16647): performing dump of process 15945 (target tid = 15945)
F/DEBUG   (16647): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
F/DEBUG   (16647): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/star2ltexx/star2lte:10/QP1A.190711.020/G965FXXU7DTAA:user/release-keys'
F/DEBUG   (16647): Revision: '26'
F/DEBUG   (16647): ABI: 'arm64'
F/DEBUG   (16647): Timestamp: 2021-02-02 08:55:09+0300
F/DEBUG   (16647): pid: 15945, tid: 15945, name: z.tigo.tigoshop  >>> tz.tigo.tigoshop <<<
F/DEBUG   (16647): uid: 10534
F/DEBUG   (16647): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4
F/DEBUG   (16647): Cause: null pointer dereference
F/DEBUG   (16647): Abort message: 'Check failed: found_virtual Didn't find oat method index for virtual method: void android.Manifest$permission.<init>()'
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x0  00000070f293b338  x1  0000000000000000  x2  000000706b0cc0b8  x3  0000000000000000
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x4  0000000000000000  x5  00000070569f31ed  x6  000000000000000a  x7  000000000000000a
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x8  0000007fecb63400  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000007fecb63400  x11 00000070f293b360
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x12 000000000a055108  x13 3d7365786574756d  x14 00000000ffffffff  x15 0000000000000000
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x16 000000706aff6ff0  x17 00000070ef69e530  x18 00000070f273c000  x19 00000070f293b338
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x20 0000000000000000  x21 000000706b14b660  x22 00000070f14f9000  x23 0000000000000000
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x24 00000070f293b338  x25 0000000000000001  x26 00000070f1686020  x27 0000000000000000
F/DEBUG   (16647):     x28 0000000000000000  x29 00000070f293b300
F/DEBUG   (16647):     sp  00000070f293b0a0  lr  000000706b506000  pc  000000706b4e8ba4
F/DEBUG   (16647): 
F/DEBUG   (16647): backtrace:
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #00 pc 00000000004ddba4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12StackVisitor9WalkStackILNS0_16CountTransitionsE0EEEvb+1556) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #01 pc 00000000004faffc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+468) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #02 pc 0000000000515434  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+820) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #03 pc 000000000050e7a0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+528) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #04 pc 000000000050d94c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+1260) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #05 pc 00000000004bac10  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1352) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #06 pc 000000000000c650  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+608) (BuildId: 74e39b9e4bda61561a36377476803040)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #07 pc 0000000000147090  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL16FindOatMethodForEPNS_9ArtMethodENS_11PointerSizeEPb.llvm.6985246053800691335+608) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #08 pc 0000000000146cc8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::GetOatQuickMethodHeader(unsigned long)+280) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #09 pc 00000000001efae0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::FaultManager::IsInGeneratedCode(siginfo*, void*, bool)+896) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #10 pc 00000000001ef3c4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*)+92) (BuildId: 9073c75c7bcb19eca4fe361a4c68592f)
F/DEBUG   (16647):       #11 pc 0000000000004dd4  /system/bin/app_process64 (art::SignalChain::Handler(int, siginfo*, void*)+588) (BuildId: a569457735bdeff7f71efb40991cc89e)
```

**Beginning of Crash 2:-**

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4551d4927d7848 in tid 22924 

E/crash_dump64(23333): unknown process state: t
I/crash_dump64(23333): obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
I/crash_dump64(23333): performing dump of process 22860 (target tid = 22924)
F/DEBUG   (23333): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
F/DEBUG   (23333): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/star2ltexx/star2lte:10/QP1A.190711.020/G965FXXU7DTAA:user/release-keys'
F/DEBUG   (23333): Revision: '26'
F/DEBUG   (23333): ABI: 'arm64'
F/DEBUG   (23333): Timestamp: 2021-02-02 11:55:06+0300
F/DEBUG   (23333): pid: 22860, tid: 22924, name: RenderThread  >>> tz.tigo.tigoshop <<<
F/DEBUG   (23333): uid: 10536
F/DEBUG   (23333): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4551d4927d7848
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x0  0000007056a04d80  x1  0000006fe1674290  x2  0000006fe1674b20  x3  0000000000000000
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x4  0000006fe16744a0  x5  2c01000090010000  x6  00000070f2941000  x7  00000000002bf056
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x8  00000070547e2a48  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000019  x11 000000000000001a
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x12 0000000000000033  x13 000000000000001a  x14 6c4551d4927d7068  x15 6c4551d4927d7068
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x16 0000000000000050  x17 00000070ed9adff0  x18 0000006fe14da000  x19 0000006fe1674290
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x20 0000006fe1675020  x21 6c4551d4927d7888  x22 6c4551d4927d7838  x23 00000070547e2a48
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x24 0000006fe1675020  x25 0000000000000001  x26 0000006fe1675020  x27 0000000000000000
F/DEBUG   (23333):     x28 0000006fe16745b0  x29 0000006fe1674250
F/DEBUG   (23333):     sp  0000006fe1674210  lr  00000070ed9ac3f4  pc  00000070ed9ac500
F/DEBUG   (23333): 
F/DEBUG   (23333): backtrace:
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #00 pc 000000000039a500  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaDisplayList::updateChildren(std::__1::function<void (android::uirenderer::RenderNode*)>)+136) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #01 pc 000000000039a3f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::syncDisplayList(android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo*)+240) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #02 pc 0000000000399874  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::prepareTreeImpl(android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, bool)+2020) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #03 pc 000000000039a8fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaDisplayList::prepareListAndChildren(android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, bool, std::__1::function<void (android::uirenderer::RenderNode*, android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, bool)>)+636) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #04 pc 00000000003993d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::prepareTreeImpl(android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, bool)+832) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #05 pc 000000000039a8fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaDisplayList::prepareListAndChildren(android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, bool, std::__1::function<void (android::uirenderer::RenderNode*, android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, bool)>)+636) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #06 pc 00000000003993d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::prepareTreeImpl(android::uirenderer::TreeObserver&, android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, bool)+832) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #07 pc 0000000000398ce8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::prepareTree(android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&)+152) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #08 pc 0000000000153044  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::RootRenderNode::prepareTree(android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&)+316) (BuildId: 97c11c0a9e40704eea4a584db87b34e1)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #09 pc 0000000000407544  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::prepareTree(android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&, long*, long, android::uirenderer::RenderNode*)+316) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #10 pc 00000000004071d8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::syncFrameState(android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&)+176) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #11 pc 0000000000406cc8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+104) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #12 pc 0000000000417a44  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+228) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #13 pc 0000000000417770  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+80) (BuildId: 343ecb7aa186fa3af5b14eab30973292)
F/DEBUG   (23333):       #14 pc 00000000000137a4  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+284) (BuildId: e401a05bdd74f2cd876793e31ceba528)
```

Can anyone help me with this stacktrace? Is there a way to find the root cause of this?